# Delegate Method is not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I am trying to pass selected cell text from CategoryViewController to DescribeViewController. But it does not call the method in the DescribeViewController method.

**CategoryViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol CategoryViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)didSelectRow:(NSString *)cellDataString;

@end

@interface CategoryViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<CategoryViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

**CategoryViewController.m**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [categoryTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *cellText = cell.textLabel.text;
    [self.delegate didSelectRow:cellText];
    [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

**DescribeViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CategoryViewController.h"

@interface DescribeViewController : ProductAwareBaseViewController<UITextFieldDelegate, CategoryViewControllerDelegate>
```

The following `didSelectRow` method is not getting called. I could not able to find out the root of the problem.

**DescribeViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.        
    CategoryViewController *popoverTableViewController = [[CategoryViewController alloc] init];
    popoverTableViewController.delegate = self;

}

- (void)didSelectRow:(NSString *)cellDataString
{
    self.cellDataString = cellDataString;
}
```

**ProductAwareBaseViewController.h**

```
@import UIKit;

@class Product;

@interface ProductAwareBaseViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) Product *product;
@end
```

**ProductAwareBaseViewController.m**

```
#import "ProductAwareBaseViewController.h"
#import "Product.h"

@interface ProductAwareBaseViewController ()

@end

@implementation ProductAwareBaseViewController

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[ProductAwareBaseViewController class]]) {
        ProductAwareBaseViewController *vc = (ProductAwareBaseViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        vc.product = self.product;
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: Where do you set the delegate property of `CategoryViewController`?  By the way, the delegate property should be `weak`

Comment: @Paulw11, I have changed to the delegate property to the weak. I am setting delegate property in the `DescribeViewController.m` in `ViewDidLoad` method. Could you please let me know what I else am missing?

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to do this?  ViewDidLoad is an odd place to do it. You need to do it as you present or segue to CategoryViewController

Comment: I added segue directly on my button, rather than defining a segue identifier. When User clicks on selectCategory button in the `DescribeViewController`, then it goes to `CategoryViewController`. Then user selects the category from the table and then it popViewController to go back to `DescribeViewController`.

Comment: It doesn't matter how you trigger the segue (or are you calling `presentViewController`? ) You need to set the pdelegate property on the destination view controller instance.

Comment: Ok I have added the piece that  you are asking. Please check my updated question. Actually `DescribeViewController` inherits from `ProductAwareBaseViewController` class which I have added and where the segue destination are declared. But I am not sure how could I add delegate there since there are multiple `Viewcontrollers` inherit from `ProductBaseAwareViewController`

Comment: You need to override `prepareForSegue` as required. It is unlikely that your base class method will be applicable to all subclasses

Answer (score 0):

try

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <CategoryViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

for declaring your delegate.

1. EDITED

try for checking the delegate is returning some value or not.
By this, whenever yo are setting the values.

```
if(self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didSelectRow:)])
    {
        [self.delegate didSelectRow:(NSString *) cellDataString];
    }
```

and also if you are using the segue to transfer the data between two controllers then check there for the delegates.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
DescribeViewController *obj = (DescribeViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
obj.delegate =self;
}
```

i think this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the delegate object in didSelectRow. And call that delegate method after that. Because delegate is weak, may be it is released from the memory.

```
CategoryViewController *popoverTableViewController = [[CategoryViewController alloc] init];
    popoverTableViewController.delegate = self;

UITableViewCell *cell = [categoryTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *cellText = cell.textLabel.text;
    [self.delegate didSelectRow:cellText];
    [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Most common reason for delegate method not being called is dealing with incorrect objects.

1. Ensure that `CategoryViewController` object created from
   `DescribeViewController` is the same which you are presenting on
   screen and that the delegate is being set on the same object. I truly believe you are creating a new `CategoryViewController` object and setting delegate on that.
2. In `DescribeViewController`, before calling delegate, check the
   existence of delegate and that it implements the protocol method (if
   its an optional method). This is a safety check, you can also put a `NSLog` statement to double check if your delegate exists or not. You are failing here.

->

```
if (delegate && [delegate respondsToSelector:(didSelectRow:)]) {
     [self.delegate didSelectRow:cellText];
}
```

**PS: If you are segueing from `DescribeViewController` to `CategoryViewController` then you set delegate in `prepareForSegue:`.**

Follow these guidelines and I am sure you would be able to fix your issue!